# Method to process commands for managing a hockey league

Tags: java, beginner

I have to shorten the method `method` in `HockeySystem`.
`Terminal.readLine` reads the line you put into the Terminal.
I have tried to split up  the method, but there seems to be problems with the 
`while`-loop in the main if I do that.
How could I shorten this?
You can ignore every other Class besides `HockeySystem` , I only put them in so that it would be compile-able

```
 public class HockeySystem {

            private static boolean var = true;
            private Team[] teams = new Team[4];
            private HockeyMatch[] hockeyMatches = new HockeyMatch[4];
            private Standings[] standings = new Standings[4];

            /**
             *
             * @param args for command-line arguments
             */
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                HockeySystem m = new HockeySystem();

                while (var == true) {

                    m.method();

                }
            }

            /**
             * This method contains multiple IF-Operations. Depending on the Input in
             * the Terminal, different operations will be executed.
             *
             * "add-team" Input : "team" will be added to the Array "teams" if "team"
             * passes multiple tests, which if it doesn't will lead to Error messages.
             * In case "teams" is full, the Array will be doubled in size.
             *
             * "list-team" Input : every "team" in the Array "teams" will be printed ,
             * each one in a new row.
             *
             * "add-ice-hockey-match" Input : "hockeyMatch" will be added to the Array
             * "hockeyMatches" if "hockeyMatch" matches the requirements. If it doesn't
             * match those , an Error message will be printed. In case "hockeyMatch" is
             * full, the Array will be doubled in size.
             *
             * "quit" Input : The program will be
             *
             */
            public void method() {
                String[] parts = Terminal.readLine().split(" ");
                if (parts[0].startsWith("add-team")) {
                    String[] parts2 = parts[1].split(";"); // parts2[0] will be the "ID" & parts 2[1] will be the "Teamname"
                    boolean hasBeenAdded = false;
                    boolean hasNameError = false;
                    boolean hasSameId = false;
                    Team team = new Team(Integer.valueOf(parts2[0]), parts2[1]);
                    for (int i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
                        if (teams[i] != null) {
                            if (teams[i].getTeamName().equals(team.getTeamName())) {
                                hasNameError = true;
                            }
                            if (teams[i].getId() == team.getId() || team.getId() == 0) {
                                hasSameId = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (teams[i] == null) {
                            if (team.getId() == 0) {
                                hasSameId = true;
                            }
                            if (hasNameError == false && hasSameId == false) {
                                teams[i] = team;
                                hasBeenAdded = true;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (hasBeenAdded == false && hasNameError == false && hasSameId == false) {
                        Team[] moreTeams = new Team[teams.length * 2];
                        moreTeams[teams.length] = team;
                        for (int i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
                            moreTeams[i] = teams[i];
                        }
                        teams = moreTeams;
                        hasBeenAdded = true;
                    }
                    if (hasNameError) {
                        Terminal.printError("A team with that Name already exists.");
                    } else if (hasSameId) {
                        Terminal.printError("A Team with that ID already exists or the ID equals 0.");
                    } else {
                        Terminal.printLine("OK");
                    }
                }
                if (parts[0].equals("list-team")) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
                        if (teams[i] != null) {
                            Terminal.printLine(teams[i].getId() + " " + teams[i].getTeamName());
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (parts[0].equals("add-ice-hockey-match")) {
                    String[] parts2 = parts[1].split(";");
                    if (Integer.valueOf(parts2[4]) >= 60 && Integer.valueOf(parts2[4]) <= 120
                            && Integer.valueOf(parts2[1]) != Integer.valueOf(parts2[3])) {
                        HockeyMatch hockeyMatch;
                        hockeyMatch = new HockeyMatch(
                                Integer.valueOf(parts2[0]),
                                Integer.valueOf(parts2[1]),
                                Integer.valueOf(parts2[2]),
                                Integer.valueOf(parts2[3]),
                                Integer.valueOf(parts2[4]));
                        boolean hasBeenAdded = false;
                        for (int i = 0; i < hockeyMatches.length; i++) {
                            if (hockeyMatches[i] != null) {
                                hockeyMatches[i] = hockeyMatch;
                                hasBeenAdded = true;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        if (hasBeenAdded == false) {
                            HockeyMatch[] moreHockeyMatches = new HockeyMatch[hockeyMatches.length * 2];
                            moreHockeyMatches[hockeyMatches.length] = hockeyMatch;
                            for (int i = 0; i < hockeyMatches.length; i++) {
                                moreHockeyMatches[i] = hockeyMatches[i];
                            }
                            hockeyMatches = moreHockeyMatches;
                            hasBeenAdded = true;
                        }
                        if (hasBeenAdded) {
                            Terminal.printLine("OK");
                        }
                    } else if (Integer.valueOf(parts2[4]) <= 60) {
                        Terminal.printError("The minimum playtime of 60minutes has not been reached.");
                    } else if (Integer.valueOf(parts2[4]) >= 120) {
                        Terminal.printError("The maximum playtime of 120minutes has been exceeded.");
                    } else if (Integer.valueOf(parts2[1]) == Integer.valueOf(parts2[3])) {
                        Terminal.printError("Tie not allowed.");
                    }
                }
                if (parts[0].equals("print-del-standings")) {
                }
            }


            public void quit(){
                var = false;
            }
        }
```

```
    public class HockeyMatch {

        private int id1;
        private int goal1;
        private int id2;
        private int goal2;
        private int playTime;

        /**
         *
         * @param id1 The first Team of the HockeyMatch
         * @param goal1 The amount of goals of the first Team
         * @param id2 The second Team of the HockeyMatch
         * @param goal2 The amount of goals of the second Team
         * @param playTime The playtime of the HockeyMatch
         */
        public HockeyMatch(int id1, int goal1, int id2, int goal2, int playTime) {
            this.id1 = id1;
            this.goal1 = goal1;
            this.id2 = id2;
            this.goal2 = goal2;
            this.playTime = playTime;
        }

    }
```

```
public class Team {

    private int id;
    private String teamName;

    /**
     * 
     * @param id the Team consists of an ID & teamname
     * @param teamName the Team consists of an ID & teamname
     */
    public Team(int id, String teamName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return the Teamname of the Team.
     */
    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return the ID of the Team.
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }





}
```

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 * This class provides some simple methods for input/output from and to a terminal as well as a method to read in
 * files.
 * 
 * <p><b>Never modify this class, never upload it to Praktomat.</b> This is only for your local use. If an assignment
 * tells you to use this class for input and output never use System.out, System.err or System.in in the same
 * assignment.
 * 
 * @author  ITI, VeriAlg Group
 * @author  IPD, SDQ Group
 * @version 5.03, 2016/05/07
 */
public final class Terminal {

    /**
     * Reads text from the "standard" input stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient reading
     * of characters, arrays, and lines. This stream is already open and ready to supply input data and corresponds
     * to keyboard input.
     */
    private static final BufferedReader IN = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    /**
     * Private constructor to avoid object generation.
     * 
     * @deprecated Utility-class constructor.
     */
    @Deprecated
    private Terminal() {
        throw new AssertionError("Utility class constructor.");
    }

    /**
     * Prints the given error-{@code message} with the prefix "{@code Error, }".
     * 
     * <p>More specific, this method behaves exactly as if the following code got executed:
     * <blockquote><pre>
     * Terminal.printLine("Error, " + message);</pre>
     * </blockquote>
     *
     * @param message the error message to be printed
     * @see   #printLine(Object)
     */
    public static void printError(final String message) {
        Terminal.printLine("Error, " + message);
    }

    /**
     * Prints the string representation of an {@code Object} and then terminate the line.
     * 
     * <p>If the argument is {@code null}, then the string {@code "null"} is printed, otherwise the object's string
     * value {@code obj.toString()} is printed.
     *
     * @param object the {@code Object} to be printed
     * @see   String#valueOf(Object)
     */
    public static void printLine(final Object object) {
        System.out.println(object);
    }

    /**
     * Prints an array of characters and then terminate the line.
     * 
     * <p>If the argument is {@code null}, then a {@code NullPointerException} is thrown, otherwise the value of {@code
     * new String(charArray)} is printed.
     * 
     * @param charArray an array of chars to be printed
     * @see   String#valueOf(char[])
     */
    public static void printLine(final char[] charArray) {
        /*
         * Note: This method's sole purpose is to ensure that the Terminal-class behaves exactly as
         * System.out regarding output. (System.out.println(char[]) calls String.valueOf(char[])
         * which itself returns 'new String(char[])' and is therefore the only method that behaves
         * differently when passing the provided parameter to the System.out.println(Object)
         * method.)
         */
        System.out.println(charArray);
    }

    /**
     * Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return
     * ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.
     *
     * @return a {@code String} containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or
     *         {@code null} if the end of the stream has been reached
     */
    public static String readLine() {
        try {
            return IN.readLine();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            /*
             * The IOException will not occur during tests executed by the praktomat, therefore the
             * following RuntimeException does not have to get handled.
             */
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reads the file with the specified path and returns its content stored in a {@code String} array, whereas the
     * first array field contains the file's first line, the second field contains the second line, and so on.
     *
     * @param  path the path of the file to be read
     * @return the content of the file stored in a {@code String} array
     */
    public static String[] readFile(final String path) {
        try (final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
            return reader.lines().toArray(String[]::new);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            /*
             * You can expect that the praktomat exclusively provides valid file-paths. Therefore
             * there will no IOException occur while reading in files during the tests, the
             * following RuntimeException does not have to get handled.
             */
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `method` to be shorter, refactor it to call other methods.  E.g.

```
public void processInput() {
    String[] parts = Terminal.readLine().split(" ");
    if (parts[0].startsWith("add-team")) {
        addTeam(parts[1].split(";"));

    }

    if (parts[0].equals("list-team")) {
        for (Team t : teams) {
            if (t != null) {
                Terminal.printLine(t.getId() + " " + t.getTeamName());
            }
        }
    }

    if (parts[0].equals("add-ice-hockey-match")) {
        addMatch(parts[1].split(";"));
    }

    if (parts[0].equals("print-del-standings")) {
    }
}
```

Now `processInput` replaces the vaguely named `method`.  It knows how to get the next line of input and how to process the first part.  It delegates processing any second part to other methods based on the result of the first part.

You could also delegate on list-team, but I didn't find that necessary.

I rewrote the `for` loop to use the foreach/range-based form.  You could also call `t` `team`, but some find having variables named `team` and `teams` confusing.  Since you never use `i` for anything but dereferencing `teams`, this was a natural to convert.

Also consider creating a `toString` for `Team`.  Then you could use that and be sure of consistent display.

Consider using a `switch` to process `parts[0]`.  Or use an `if`/`else if` structure.  As is, it would try to match even after it found a match.  Even though the `if` conditions are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can do is what @mdfst13 say : *"delegates processing any second part to other methods"*

If you want to have a cleaner code, you can introduce `Command` and a `CommandParser` that parse an `InputStream` to create `Command` that you execute on your `HockeySystem`.

Some use annotations on methods or use naming conventions (and conversions). I made a simple application with this idea some years ago. It is written with Scala, but the main idea is easy to understand :

```
if ( args.length>0 ) {
  val command = args(0) // he first argument is the command
  val arguments = args.drop(1) // The command parameters
  getClass.getMethod(command, arguments.getClass) 
    .invoke(this, arguments)
} else {
  help(Array(""))
}

// Each "command" method has the name of the command and expect an array of string for parameters

def list(args:Array[String]) {
  // ...
}

def add(args:Array[String]) {
  val team = args(1)
  val text = args.drop(2).mkString(" ")
  val res = // Execute 
  println(s"Ok (#${res.id.toString})")
}
```

This is simple but works well.

Based on this idea you can create a class dedicated to convert a string to a method. So that you move the parsing logic away from your business logic. You can continue on this idea by moving the argument parsing (`new Team(Integer.parseInt(parts2[0]), parts2[1])`) to a dedicated class (*adapter pattern*) that will just parse the string to create your domain objects and call the business logic on your `HockeySystem`.

(You can see the result on https://github.com/gervaisb/stackexchange-codereview/tree/q186449/src/main/java/q186449)